# i have problems with display inline image in gmail

Tags: c#, asp.net, gmail-api

i save body of gmail in database as html and when i get it.
and  try to send an email with this data it return this cod

```html
<div class="MailBody">
            <span id="lblBody"><div dir="ltr">hhhh<div><img src="cid:ii_j0rypkcz0_15b0f47a21a915c8" width="477" height="477"><br><br></div></div>
</span>
        </div>
```

and image can't be display 
any body  see this error before

Comment: Maybe you could get some inspiration from [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42864666/node-js-gmail-api-getting-inline-embedded-images).

Comment: I think you are not saving those images but just the src of image, you need to download those images attached with the body of gmail and save them somewhere, after you get the stored db data of html body, attach those stored images too.

Comment: But I  used C# and i don't have any idea about how can i save this image and in case it more than one image  @Tholle